# what is the suggested integration pattern for running Mahout jobs using the data stored in Cassandra?

Tags: mahout, datastax-enterprise

I use Cassandra from DataStax enterprise version (3.1.4). I would like Mahout to access the data stored in Cassandra instead of requiring a HDFS file.

How can a Mahout job access data stored in a Cassandra CQL table ? Not able to run a mahout job that depends on DataStax CQL JDBC driver. It complains that the driver as well related CQL  classes are not in the classpath. This error is seen despite adding CQL driver jar files in the Mahout classpath. We found that Hector APIs are bundled with the Mahout jars but not CQL java driver. Can CQL APIs be used with Mahout?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out CQLStorage loader for Pig?

You can grab a CF and map/reduce on it e.g. https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/trunk/examples/pig/test/test_cql_storage.pig?source=cc and use the org.apache.mahout.pig.LogisticRegression UDF for Pig with Mahout.

There are also DSE commands for Mahout http://www.datastax.com/docs/datastax_enterprise3.1/solutions/mahout#mahout-example